# How do I upload a file with mod_python?

Tags: python, upload, mod-python

I want to create a simple file upload form and I must be completely incapable. I've read docs and tutorials,but for some reason, I'm not getting the submitted form data. I wrote the smallest amount of code I could to test and it still isn't working. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
def index():
    html = '''
    <html>
      <body>
      <form id="fileUpload" action="./result" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
      </form>
      </body>
    </html>
    '''
    return html

def result(req):
    try: tmpfile = req.form['file']
    except:
        return "no file!"
```

Comment: Are you using web2py framework?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you have an error trace?  Also, why aren't you using mod_wsgi?

Comment: @S.Lott "I'm not getting the submitted form data." I don't know about wsgi.

Comment: @scotty2012: "not getting" -- what does that mean?  Traceback?  Silence?  404 error?  500 error?   See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ for a better interface than mod_python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag. Your mistake is not really mod_python related.

Comment: that's was the problem. I went back and looked at the mod_python docs and their example doesn't have that tag.